# Check if coordinates are within given distance of any points in another matrix

Tags: matlab, performance, matrix, distance

In Matlab, I have two rather big matrices (A and B) containing coordinates. The two lines stand for x and y and every column represents a cartesian coordinate (x;y).

Now I want to store all points from matrix B which are closer than 1 (meter) to any point in matrix A in a new matrix.

I can loop through all the data, but it is very time consuming (the matrices are 2x800000).

Is there any way to boost the performance?

---

This is the structure of my current code:

```
new_vec = [0;0];
for i=1:length(A)
    cur_x = A(1, i);
    cur_y = A(2, i);

    for j=1:length(B)
        if B(2, j) <= cur_y + 1 && B(2, j) >= cur_y - 1 && ...
               B(1, j) <= cur_x + 1 && B(1, j) >= cur_x - 1
            new_vec = [new_vec, [B(1, j); B(2, j)]];
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Now that you've provided code, I see your definition of "closer than 1" consists of separate checks on x and y. This means your points could have a distance of sqrt(2) and not be within range - is this intentional or would you rather use a direct 2D (Euclidean) distance?

Comment: It is intentional, but thanks for the hint

Comment: @m7913d Note that `pdist2` could be used, but may be event slower for data of this size where we just want to know if any distance is less than 1. Also they want x and y coordinates to be +/-1, rather than within 1 unit, so would probably need to use the "city block distance" somehow

Comment: @Wolfie You can specify the [distance metric using `pdist2`](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html#inputarg_Distance). `cityblock` is one of the available options.

Comment: How much memory do you have? Are the coordinates integers or doubles?

Comment: coordinates are doubles, memory shouldn't be a problem, the current device has 8gb, but later it will run with 16 or 32gb RAM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use [`pdist2`](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) as follows:

```
new_vec = B(:, any(pdist2(A', B', 'Chebychev') < 1, 1));
```

Note that `pdist2` will always faster than your method, but may be slower than Wolfie's suggestion, because `pdist2` always calculates all the distances between all points of `A` and `B`.

**Comparision**

I will compare:

- *Original*: The code you provided in your answer
- *Optimised*: The code provided by Wolfie
- *pdist2*: my solution using `pdist2`
- *bsxfun*: rahnema1's answer
- *bsxfun (>=2016b)*: rahnema1's answer using new 2016b functionality

using the following sample data

```
A = rand(2, N)*N*relativeAmplitude;
B = rand(2, N)*N*relativeAmplitude;
```

The execution time in function of `N` and for `relativeAmplitude=1`:
[image]

The execution time in function of `relativeAmplitude` and for `N=10000`:
[image]

**Conclusion**

All the solutions (Wolfie's, rahnema1's and mine) are faster than the original algorithm.

**Optimised (Wolfie) vs `pdist2` (mine)**: If it is likely that an index of `B` will be found in `A`, then Wolfie's answer may be 50x faster, but if it is unlikely, `pdist` may be 50% faster. Note that the execution time of my solution is independent of `relativeAmplitude`, while Wolfie's isn't, but Wolfie's answer may be much faster in some cases.

**`bsxfun` (rahnema1) vs `pdist2` (mine)**: Without the new R2016b functionality, `bsxfun` is always ~50% slower than `pdist2`, otherwise both methods are always (almost) equally fast.

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark, yes it'll be very important how early one expects to find a point which satisfies the distance.

Answer (score 2):

Performance improvements *based on your current implementation*:

```
% Appending is bad practise for memory management, you should initialise the 
% entire output array at first.
new_vec = NaN(size(B));
% You should not use i as a loop variable, since you are overwriting the default i=sqrt(-1)
% Also length(A)=max(size(A)), clearer to use size(A,2)

% Loops have been swapped as we want to exit the *A* looping when satisfied
for jj=1:size(B,2)
    % No need to re-assign current variables each loop, waste of time/memory

    % Same as before, j also is sqrt(-1) by default!
    % We could remove this loop entirely using vectorization, but it's likely quicker to
    % loop *until the condition is satisfied* then exit the loop early, avoiding many ops.
    for ii=1:size(A,2)
        % We can *half* the number of logical operations by using the abs distance!
        if abs(B(2,jj)-A(2,ii)) <= 1 && abs(B(1,jj) - A(1,ii)) <= 1
            % We pre-allocated, so no need to append - use direct indexing
            new_vec(:,jj) = B(:,jj);
            % Now the condition is satisfied for B(:,jj), exit the jj loop!
            break;
        end
    end
end
% We initialised an array of NaNs, remove the columns which are still NaN
new_vec(:, isnan(new_vec(1,:))) = [];
```

The highlights:

- Best practise: don't use `i` or `j` as loop variables, they have a default value of `sqrt(-1)`
- [Pre-allocate memory, don't append results during looping](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html).
- Reduce the number of logical checks, using `abs` to do absolute distance checks.
- Don't assign temporary variables each loop when you don't have to.
- Because you are happy when a given `B` coordinate is within distance of *any* `A` coordinate, **exit the loop early** to avoid even further checks.

---

An (potentially more memory-friendly) alternative to initialising a 2D array of `NaN`s would be to initialise a Boolean `false` array, then make it true at every satisfying `jj` index. At the end we would then do `new_vec = B(:,booleanVector);`

Comment: good point with `i` and `j`. I'm used to C and Python syntax.


I didn't preallocate because the resulting vector will be less than 1% the size of B. Is this reasonable?


if the loop breaks at the first match only the first match will be covered or am I missing anything?

Comment: @user3932876 I have suggested (at the bottom) that you pre-allocate a 1D Boolean array, then use logical indexing. This will be more memory efficient. I have also swapped the loops around so that all `B(:,jj)` which are within 1  (x and y) of any `A(:,ii)` will be stored.

Comment: @user3932876 Reading your comment again, it might be useful for me to clarify that `break` will only exit the *inner* loop, then proceed to the next `jj`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorized solution:

```
cur_x = A(1,:);
cur_y = A(2,:);
B1= reshape(B(1,:),[],1);
B2= reshape(B(2,:),[],1);
condition = abs(bsxfun(@minus,B2,cur_y))<=1 & ...
            abs(bsxfun(@minus,B1,cur_x))<=1;

[x ,~]=find(condition);
new_vec = [[0;0] B(:,x)];
```

As of MATLAB r2016b you can write `condition` as:

```
condition = abs(B2-cur_y)<=1 & ...
            abs(B1-cur_x)<=1;
```

or

```
condition = B2 <= cur_y + 1 & B2 >= cur_y - 1 & ...
               B1 <= cur_x + 1 & B1 >= cur_x - 1;
```

*idea of `abs(B(2,jj)-A(2,ii)) <= 1` stolen from @Wolfie answer.